# Out of sample testing Geographically Weighted Regression

Tags: regression, spatial

I have spatial data on property prices and I've fitted a GWR, calibrated on all points.

I haven't seen cross-validation or out-of-sample testing approaches applied to many GWR models in literature, Is it necessary/possible to test the GWR on out-of-sample data?

For my model, the bandwidth is calibrated using Leave one out cross-validation, and a prediction is made for each observation in the data. Is it acceptable to compare the accuracy of these predictions to 5-fold cross validation for a global regression model, say?